# android progressbar with separate items (bars)

Tags: android

i wanted to create a progressbar with separate items, like this:

[image]

as you see in the horizontal progressbar, there are some vertical bars (every X% one will be added). the background is no problem, i could use a LinearLayout with a style, but i really have no idea how to place these bars in it (i have the red ones as image, but can create them also with xml if its neccessary).

but is this generally possible or am i forced to use a "normal" progressbar?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a layout for your progressbar with all of your red bars included.  Have their [visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) set to INVISIBLE initially, and then when you reach appropriate progress percentage, set their visibility programattically to VISIBLE.

Comment: i already thought about this, but i suggest this isn't the cleanest method. a "nice to have" would be if the amount of red bars vary depending on the screen width (large screen = more bars, but smaller steps)

Comment: If you want to go that route, you can always programmatically create the LinearLayout after getting the device's [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) to determine the appropriate number of red bars to add to the layout before showing it.

Comment: yeah that would be a solution. but maybe it is also possible with `progressbar`? if not i will be using this way