# android: set visibility from AsyncTask

Tags: android

after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069532/android-progressbar-with-seperate-items-bars) thread, i tried to make a variable status bar with this code:

```
private int[] loadingElementIDs;
private void initLoadingBar() {
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics=getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final float screenWidthInDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels/displayMetrics.density;
    final int elementAmount = (int) (Math.floor(screenWidthInDp * 0.5f / 30) * 5);

    //set margins
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loading_outer);
    ...
    container.requestLayout();

    //declare length
    loadingElementIDs = new int[elementAmount];

    LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LLParams.weight = 1f;
    LinearLayout element;
    for (int i=0; i<elementAmount; i++) {
        int id = generateViewId(); //creates unique id

        element = new LinearLayout(this);
        element.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        element.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
        element.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loading_inner));
        element.setId(id);
        element.requestLayout();            
        container.addView(element);

        loadingElementIDs[i] = id;
    }

}
```

this is working fine for me, but now i want to calculate sth with an asynctask and make the elements visible (code within my activity class):

```
private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {
            int step = 0; 
            float totalSteps = 100f;
            while (...) {
                step++;

                // ...................

                //show status
                setLoadingStatus( step / totalSteps);
            }               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

}

public void setLoadingStatus(float percentage) {
    int max = (int) Math.min( Math.floor(percentage * loadingElementIDs.length), 
    for (int d=0; d<max; d++ ) {
        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(loadingElementIDs[d])).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayout el = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(loadingElementIDs[d]);
        el.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And this does not work. if i call `setLoadingStatus(20f);` from onCreate it works perfectly, but not in the AsyncTask. Of course i do start `initLoadingBar();` and `new PrefetchData().execute();` in activities onCreate().

do you know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can't call UI functions from doInBackground(), it is a separate thread (that is the whole purpose of AsnycTasks). You need to do it in onProgressUpdate() or onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys, i solved it with `onProgressUpdate`. instead of `setLoadingStatus` i call this:

```
private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Float, Void> {
    ....
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
        for (int d=0; d<Math.min( Math.floor(values[0] * loadingElementIDs.length), loadingElementIDs.length); d++ ) {
            LinearLayout el = (LinearLayout)findViewById(loadingElementIDs[d]);
            el.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this got merged, the comment is all borked, but the requested code snippet is below for managing this with a Handler:

define a handler in your activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){

   handleMessage(Message msg)
   {
      if (msg.what == STATUS)
      { 
          //do something if it's a message form your AsyncTask
      }
      else
        //other messages..
   }

};
```

when creating your AsyncTask, give it your handler. define a constructor to accept this and keep a local reference to it.

```
new PrefetchData(handler).execute(...);
```

and then inside your AsyncTask: (STATUS would be a constant setup as the message code.. )

```
 while (...) {
            step++;

            // ...................

            //show status
            handler.obtainMessage(STATUS, step / totalSteps).sendToTarget();
        }
```

Comment: do you have an example how i could solve it with handlers (within AsyncTask?)

Answer (score 1):

Use UI thread for update UI components. If you need to update task progress, you can use publishProgress(xxx) and onProgressUpdate(xxx). For more dateils: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You can `runOnUiThread` method to call Ui functions from any `thread`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)
    }
}); // enter code here
```

Comment: i cannot use Runnable, because i need `onPostExecute`